# Rails :include in a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

have a standard

```
def mutual_friends(friend)
  self.friends & friend.friends
end
```

Trying to `:include => :profile`

Can this be done?

If not, can someone help me with a scope version of this?

Given that User has:

```
has_one  :profile, :dependent => :destroy    
has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :friends, 
         :through => :friendships,
         :conditions => "status = 'accepted'"
```

Comment: if you want to include the profile just do something like this in your model: `default_scope includes(:profile)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question there are 2 ways to do this.
The Rails way
1) Create a module (in your libs folder) add the shared methods to that module and include the module in the classes where needed.

or

The OO way
2) Create a base class descended from ActiveRecord::Base, make it an abstract class to avoid STI and add the common methods to the base class then descend Friend and Friendships from that

Option 1 example
Friend model

```
#You might need to require the friends module for Rails 3
require 'friends'
include Friends
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
#...
end
```

Just do the same in profile model and any other classes that need this
Friends module a file called friends.rb in lib folder

```
module Friends
    module ClassMethods
      #put your class methods here e.g.
      def self.some_class_method
      end
    end

    #put you instance methods here e.g.
    def another_method
    end

 #  extend host class with class methods when we're included
    def self.included(host_class)
      host_class.extend(ClassMethods)
    end

end
```

Option 2 example
base_friends.rb in models folder (Or libs if you prefer)

```
class BaseFriends < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  #All you usual methods that you want to share in the usual model way here
end
```

Friend model
Again - just do the same in profile and any other models that need this

```
class Friend < BaseFriends
  #...
end
```

I prefer option 2 - It's much cleaner you have all the files in the same place (the models folder) and it's intuitive (You are already familiar with working in the model layer) plus this is what Ruby is all about (OO) Option 1 is more for when you want multiple inheritance which Rails does not allow for very good reason.

That answers your question but I think your question is wrong
You wouldn't do this through a method. No need and it doesn't make sense. Either approach above will allow you to share common methods plus Friends and Friendships would normally work from the same table and would therefore be the same class anyway you would just add class_name and foreign_key declarations to your has_many friendships and belongs_to friends declarations.